# My page scrolls whenever I zoom in my agm-map via ctrl+scrollwheel

Tags: html, angular, google-maps, web-applications

I am working on an Angular webapplication and I want to be able to zoom in my agm-map with ctrl+scrollwheel, without scrolling the page up and down. At the same time I want to be able to scroll the page normally when not pressing ctrl, because the map covers a lot of the screen and it would be awkward to scroll past it otherwise.

At first the problem was to only get the map to scroll when ctrl was pressed. Following documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction) and comments from other developers this was achieved by setting gestureHandling to cooperative and scrollWheel to null.

Now I can scroll the page normally even when hovering over the map by scrolling without pressing ctrl and still use the scrollwheel to zoom in and out within the map when pressing ctrl. But whenever I do the later the whole page scrolls up or down a bit as well.

I tried to forego setting scrollwheel to null in the agm-map, but then the map doesn't need me to use ctrl anymore despite gestureHandling still being set to cooperative and the webpage still scrolls when zooming in the map. I tried the same setup in other views of the Webapp to see if the problem occurs consistently and it does. It also happens in both Chrome and Firefox. I tried to stop eventPropagation but I wasn't sure how to do it so it only stops when I also press ctrl.

Besides this issue everything I have set up in the map works fine (Some polygons and buttons. The bounds are set dynamically).

```
<div class="mapContainer mt-4">
      <agm-map [scrollwheel]="null" [gestureHandling]="'cooperative'" [latitude]="mapLat" [longitude]="mapLng" [fitBounds]="mapBoundsLiteral" [mapTypeControl]="true" [mapTypeId]="'satellite'" [streetViewControl]="false" #map> 
[...]
      </agm-map>
</div>
```

I'd expect the page and map to act exactly like it does in the first demo in the documentation as I use the same attributes where they seem relevant. This means the page should scroll normally when using just the scrollwheel but shouldn't scroll when I zoom the map with ctrl+scrollwheel, but the page always scrolls.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?